# How to to implement train test split without overlaps in apache beam?

Tags: apache-beam, train-test-split

I would like to train test split a list of texts with the associated entities so there are no entities overlapping splits.

Ensuring no overlaps is challenging I currently achieve it with 2 `groupby` operations. I was wondering **how I can mitigate the memory bottleneck these `groupby` operations** create or if there is a cleaner way to do the whole process.

**INPUT**

```
ENTITIES TEXT
e1       TextA
e1, e2   TextB
e3       TextC
```

I would like to have the outputs:

**TRAIN SPLIT**

```
ENTITIES TEXT
e1       TextA
e1, e2   TextB
```

**TEST SPLIT**

```
ENTITIES TEXT
e3       TextC
```

**MY APPROACH**

Initial `groupby` entities:

```
e1 [{"text":"TextA", "entities":["e1"]}, {"text":"TextB", "entities":["e1","e2"]}]
e2 [{"text":"TextB", "entities":["e1","e2"]}]
e3 [{"text":"TextC", "entities":["e3"]}]
```

Next I create a cooccuring entity key:

```
e1-e2 {"text":"TextA", "entities":["e1"]}
e1-e2 {"text":"TextB", "entities":["e1","e2"]}
e1-e2 {"text":"TextB", "entities":["e1","e2"]}
e3 {"text":"TextC", "entities":["e3"]}
```

I then `groupby` on this cooccuring key:

```
e1-e2 [{"text":"TextA", "entities":["e1"]}, {"text":"TextB", "entities":["e1","e2"]}]
e3 [{"text":"TextC", "entities":["e3"]}]
```

My job on a larger dataset with 7 million entries fails on the `groubpy` operations see errors below.

Then do the train test split with `partition` and finally take apply `distinct` to remove duplicates.

**ERRORS**

Sadly my approach fails here with:

```
  logger:  "root:shuffle.py:try_split"   
  message:  "Refusing to split <dataflow_worker.shuffle.GroupedShuffleRangeTracker object at 0x7fab8a9d2a58> at b'\x9f|\xe7c\x00\x01': proposed split position is out of range [b'\x95n*A\x00\x01', b'\x9f|\xe7c\x00\x01'). Position of last group processed was b'\x9f|\xe7b\x00\x01'."
```

```
  logger:  "root:shuffle.py:request_dynamic_split"   
  message:  "Refusing to split GroupedShuffleReader <dataflow_worker.shuffle.GroupedShuffleReader object at 0x7fab8a9d2588> at n3znYwAB"
```

Comment: I would recommend a hash based approach here because it can be made parallel, has less memory requirements, and will produce consistent splits as the dataset evolves.  I don't know enough beam yet to provide a solution, but maybe others can.

Answer (score 1):

These error messages are about Dataflow's [dynamic resharding](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/no-shard-left-behind-dynamic-work-rebalancing-in-google-cloud-dataflow), nothing to do with your particular notion of splits. They should not be fatal to your job. (Are they?)

That being said, I don't think it's possible to do this with a single grouping. For example, imagine one had

```
ENTITIES TEXT
e1       TextA
e1, e2   TextB
e2, e3   TextC
...
eN, eN+1 TextX
```

It would take O(N) groupings to discover the relationship between TextA and TextX. (Essentially what you're trying to do here is look for disjoint connected components.)

Comment: Removing overlaps can be done with 2 groupings. 

My jobs definitely get stuck after these errors and I am not sure what is happening to them. After the sharding errors the number of elements don't increase in any of the tasks even if I leave it running for hours.

Doing 2 `groupby` operations does get me the disjoint connected components. At least it works for smaller datasets. For my larger 7 million element dataset it doesn't work sadly.

Comment: Hmm... So if you had e2, e4 in TextD, and e4, e5 in TextE, how would you discover the "e1-e2-e4-e5" key? Or is there a constraint in your data about how entities are distributed? By "failing" I assume you mean not making any progress? Is this happening in the first or second groupby?

Answer (score 0):

To tackle this without using a `GroupBy`:

```
def combine_entities(values):
  res = set()
  for value in values:
    res.add(value)
  return list(res)

def split_fn(example,train,test):
  """
  3 cases:
    example["entities"] only contains elements that are also in train --> label as train
    example["entities"] only contains elements that are also in test --> label as test
    example["entities"] contains both elements in train and test --> for this never to happen you need an extra constraint (as @robertwb mentioned) on your data.
  """
    return example, "train"

unique_entities = (p
                   | 'Extract' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x["entities"])
                   | 'CombineSet' >> beam.CombineGlobally(combine_entites))

ttrain,ttest = uniq | 'Split' >> beam.Partition(lambda x: hash(x) % 100 < 80, 2)
res  = (p
        | 'Split' >> beam.Map(split_fn,
                       train=beam.pvalue.AsList(ttrain),
                       test=beam.pvalue.AsList(ttest))
```